# Finding the restore bounds of a JFrame when it is in a maximized state

Tags: java, swing

When a JFrame is in a maximized state, the `getBounds` method returns bounds that match its current state. What I need is the "restore bounds" (that is, the size/location of what the window would be set to if a user clicked on "Restore Down" on a Windows platform) without actually setting it to a non-maximized state.

The reason I ask is because I wish to save the bounds as a preference and then when the user reopens the application, set the window to the saved bounds (and then maximize it if that is what the last state was).

I considered adding a listener for when a window is maximized but it seems to me that the listener is notified *after* its maximized and I'll need to be notified right *before* it is maximized.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I store the `extendedState`, window location and frame size in the user preferences in my application. Adding a `ComponentListener` is the way to go. You will have to listen to the `componentMoved`, `componentResized`, and `componentShown` methods. When the value returned from `frame.getExtendedState() == JFrame.NORMAL`, store the Rectangle from `frame.getBounds()` as your non-maximized value. If `getExtendedState()` returns `JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH`, then don't store the current bounds, but do store the fact that it is extended. As long as you only store the value from the last `JFrame.NORMAL` extended state, you will be good.

Comment: Why is componentShown method needed?

Comment: @this is a dead end, Honestly, I don't remember. I copied this from how I had it implemented in my code and don't have that code with me. Just from reading it now it appears the componentShown method can be ignored as *moved* and *resized* should cover all situations.

Comment: Yeah I noticed because I was trying to do the same thing as you. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I considered adding a listener for
>   when a window is maximized but it
>   seems to me that the listener is
>   notified after its maximized and I'll
>   need to be notified right before it is
>   maximized.

That should work. Add a listener to handle component resized. When the event is fired, before updating the saved bounds, you check to make sure that the window is not in its maximized state.